# Is there a reference on the space of Lipschitz continuous functions?

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

I have hard a time finding the specific properties I'm looking for, I'm wondering if there is literature which proves (or disproves) that the space of all Lipschitz continuous functions of some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ forms a Banach space under some yet-to-be-specified norm, and, which also forms algebra under conventional multiplication (or some other form yet to be defined).

The space of continuous functions is complete, and forms an algebra, so I could potentially go through analogous proofs. But my work would be inconsequential because I need to confirm the results with reputable sources to be 100% sure, since I would based future results off those answers.

Comment: Check out Weaver - Lipschitz algebras

Answer (score 3):

On these matter I recommend without doubt the book of Renato Fiorenza [1], which deals with Hölder function spaces, including the space $C^{0,1}$ of Lipschitz continuous functions. The treatment is somewhat less abstract than in other monographs, its "concreteness" being aimed toward applications of these function spaces in the theory of partial differential equations. In particular, the vector and algebraic structure of these spaces (and of their local versions) is analyzed in detail in the first chapter of [1], §1.2 pp. 13-16.

**Reference**

[1] Renato Fiorenza, *Hölder and locally Hölder continuous functions, and open sets of class $C^k$, $C^{k,\lambda}$* (English), Frontiers in Mathematics, Basel: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-47939-2/pbk; 978-3-319-47940-8/ebook), pp. xi+152 (2016), [MR3588287](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR3588287), [Zbl 1366.26003](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1366.26003).